# ejabberd 18.03 on Raspberry Pi 2, ejabberdctl fails due to missing libtinfo.so.6

Tags: linux, ubuntu, raspberry-pi, raspbian, ejabberd

I am trying to get ejabberd working on a Raspberry Pi 2 using the Linux ARMv7 binary installer from ProcessOne here:
https://www.process-one.net/en/ejabberd/downloads/

After installation, trying to add a user, or start/stop ejabberd, ejabberdctl fails with the following error:

```
/opt/ejabberd-18.03/bin/beam.smp: error while loading shared libraries: libtinfo.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

When I do `sudo find / -name 'libtinfo.so*' | more` I get the following ouput:

```
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libtinfo.so
/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libtinfo.so.5.9
/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libtinfo.so.5
```

That is, libtinfo.so.6 seems not to be on the system but required by ejabberd (or at least by ejabberdctl).

I have tried this both with the latest Raspbian Stretch Lite image here: https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/

and also with the Ubuntu 16.04 LTS 'classic' image for the Pi here:
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ARM/RaspberryPi

(I also tried after an `apt-get dist-upgrade` with the Ubuntu image to get to 16.04.4).

Finally, I also installed ejabberd v18.01, but the same happens.

I don't want to use the ejabberd versions packaged with Raspbian or Ubuntu, as they are old and don't support the XMPP features I want to use. I tried the packaged Ubuntu version on my Intel machine and after many struggles moved to the binary installer for 64bit x86 binary installer from ProcessOne to get v18.01 (now upgraded to v18.03) which works perfectly.

Oddly, when I do the same `sudo find / -name 'libtinfo.so*' | more` on my Intel system (where ejabberd works without any problems), the output is:

```
/opt/ejabberd-18.03/lib/linux-x86_64/libtinfo.so.5
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.5.9
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.5
```

...that is, on the working x86_64 system, libtinfo.so.6 doesn't seem to be needed.

Can anyone help me on this? I have searched to find a way of updating libtinfo on the RPi, but not found how to do this. Or is there something I can do do convince ejabberdctl to work with libtinfo.so.5?

Thanks in advance if anyone has any tips.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone has the same question, there are two solutions:

1. Wait for ejabberd v18.04 - https://github.com/processone/ejabberd/issues/2381
2. Use Fedora 27 on the Pi, instead of Raspbian or Ubuntu 16.04. Fedora 27 contains libtinfo.so.6 out of the box